# Data Factory "The segment condition '@body....' is not valid"

Tags: database, api, rest, azure-data-factory

Im working in Microsoft Azure Data Factory.
I'm attempting to create a Copy Data activity that takes an input "userId" and return an output to me.

The structure of this, is the following:

1. I created a variable with the "Set Variable" activity
2. This leads to a "Copy Data" activity, which uses the variable and sends it to a Rest Resource dataset
3. This Rest Resource has a parameter i named "comon" which is equal to the variable from before. The Rest Resource links to a Rest Service
4. This Rest Service contains a parameter: "variable" which is equal to the "comon" parameter. The Rest Service then uses the "variable" in its Base URL which contains the API call.

With this structure i was hoping to make the API call, with whatever variable used in step 1 above.
However, when attempting to "preview data" with a variable i get the following error:

```
[
 {
  "result": "error",
  "message": "The segment condition '@body(&amp;#039' is not valid")
  }
]
```

I have nailed the problem down to step 3 above for the following reason:
The API call works fine, if I don't use the "comon" variable and instead just hardcode the "variable" from step 4 to being equal to my original variable.
However when i try to implemented the "comon" again, I go back to having my error.

Below are screenshots of my Data Factory Pipeline:

[Variable to Copy Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud7C5.png)

[Copy Data Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aou8u.png)

[Rest Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFh9W.png)

[Rest Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up80r.png)

[Rest Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5diI7.png)

And this is where I can hardcode to variable to make it work:

[Hardcoded instead of parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZJTa.png)

But if I instead hardcode it in "Parameters" it doesn't work:

[Not working again...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtgR6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your pipeline. Although it succeeded, but I didn't get the URL I expected.
I got this:`http://localhost:8080/test/Test?parameter=@body('Copy data1ComposeRuntimeVariables')?.RestResource1cec80568393745918b91c3a6b6cfece4.comon`.
It seems value of `@dataset().comon` didn't pass to link service.

Then I deleted parameter in link service and used Relative URL like this:
[image]

It worked fine, and I got my expected URL:`http://localhost:8080/test/Test/?parameter=userId==0023`.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up doing something similar yesterday. However I chose to concat my API with my Var inside my "set variable" activity.